# Unexpected host with OkHttp

Tags: android, get, okhttp

I am trying to send a query through a get request, the problem is I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected host`

```
   HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .host("10.0.2.2" + "/api/" + 7) // This is where the error is coming in
            .addQueryParameter("lat", deviceLat[0])
            .addQueryParameter("long", deviceLong[0])
            .build();


    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
```

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: are you using wamp server?

Comment: @Akhilesh Patil nope, Using docker, I know that the url is correct because I got information from there with out any queries.

Comment: Are you using emulator or device?

Comment: Sorry I should add, specifically I'm using nginx xD

Comment: I am using an emulator

Comment: try use with port no 80 or 8080 whatever port you are using for nginx

Comment: I am using port 80, but as I said, it does connect fine it's just when i try and use queries

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue there is that the `.host(string)` method is expecting just the *host* part of the url. Removing the path segments will work. Your code should look like this:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
        .scheme("http")
        .host("10.0.2.2") //Just the host (like "google.com", not "google.com/api")
        .addPathSegment("api")
        .addPathSegment("7")
        .addQueryParameter("lat", deviceLat[0])
        .addQueryParameter("long", deviceLong[0])
        .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

I try this code and it worked

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("www.google.com")
            .addPathSegment("search")
            .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
            .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
```

So, there is something wrong with your host. Please test your host on Postman or open new port for it. I also ping that host 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`HttpUrl` has a parse method for parsing Strings which I find to be much shorter.

```
HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("http://10.0.2.2/api/7")
                     .addQueryParameter("lat", deviceLat[0])
                     .addQueryParameter("long", deviceLong[0])
                     .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have no idea what the problem is that I can't build the URL, but the second that I made the url in the string manually, it worked fine and everything made it to the server no problem.

Basically I changed from this

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .host("10.0.2.2" + "/api/" + 7) // This is where the error is coming in
            .addQueryParameter("lat", deviceLat[0])
            .addQueryParameter("long", deviceLong[0])
            .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
```

to this

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url("10.0.2.2" + "/api/" + 7 + "?long=" + deviceLong[0] + "&lat=" + deviceLat[0])
                                .build();
```

And it worked fine

Comment: The host shouldn’t contain `/API/7`, that’s the path.